# Can we directly throw ResponseStatusException from service layer without throwing custom exception and handling at the controller level?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

Spring 5 has introduced ResponseStatusException, is it a good practice to throw this exception directly from the service layer.

**Case 1:**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public User findUserByName(String username) {
       User user = userRepository.findByUsernName(username);
       if(null == user) {
          throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "user not found");
       }
    }
}
```

**Case 2:**
Or do we need to use custom exception and handle it in controller level ? We are catching the CustomException and throwing ResponseStatusException in this case, why do we have to catch the custom exception again instead of going with `Case 1`

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public User findUserByName(String username) {
       User user = userRepository.findByUsernName(username);
       if(null == user) {
          throw new UserNotFoundException("user not found");
       }
    }
}

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping(path="/get-user")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(String username) {
      try {
         userService.findUserByName(username);
      } catch (UserNotFoundException ex) {
         throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "user not found");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't. The `ResponseStatusException` is a web specific exception, you don't want to tie your service layer to the web. Instead use an `@ExceptionHandler` to transform the `UserNotFoundException` to what you want instead of adding a `try/catch` block.

Comment: Totally agree with @M.Deinum. You can also annotate your `UserNotFoundException` with `@ResponseStatus` if you don't want to create a dedicated `@ExceptionHandler`. Another option is using [Errors Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/alimate/errors-spring-boot-starter) if you need more elaborate error handling and reporting.

Answer (score 6):

As it was mentioned in comments, you can create mapping in your error. Then you do not need to use try block in controller.

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "user not found")
public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public UserNotFoundException(String message) {

        super(message);
    }
}
```